# How to secure passwords and secret keys in Django settings file

Tags: python, django

A django settings file includes sensitive information such as the secret_key, password for database access etc which is unsafe to keep hard-coded in the setting file. I have come across various suggestions as to how this information can be stored in a more secure way including putting it into environment variables or separate configuration files. The bottom line seems to be that this protects the keys from version control (in addition to added convenience when using in different environments) but that in a compromised system this information can still be accessed by a hacker.
Is there any extra benefit from a security perspective if sensitive settings are kept in a data vault / password manager and then retrieved at run-time when settings are loaded?

For example, to include in the settings.py file (when using pass):

```
import subprocess
SECRET_KEY=subprocess.check_output("pass SECRET_KEY", shell=True).strip().decode("utf-8")
```

This spawns a new shell process and returns output to Django. Is this more secure than setting through environment variables?

Comment: The secret key is secure if the place where it is located is equally secure. Keep things simple. Use the `SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')` . And store your secret key in a secure file too. **The server login and password is the most important**, because if it is compromised then all the app is it too.

Comment: +1 on grabbing from env, at least until you have a more experienced view of secrets.  But dont forget to keep your env setting mechanism’s *values* out of source control.  If a bad guy is capable of sniffing your env values, you have problems anyway. Set `DEBUG = False` to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I think a data vault/password manager solution is a matter of transferring responsibility but the risk is still here. 
When deploying Django in production, the server should be treated as importantly as a data vault. Firewall in place, fail to ban, os up to date... must be in place. 
Then, in my opinion, there is nothing wrong or less secure than having a settings.py file with a config parser reading a config.ini file (declared in your .gitignore!) where all your sensitive information is present.

Comment: Keeping the server secure is the primary line of defense. But if that is compromised, would it not help if the sensitive data in django settings is  encrypted (in a password manager) as an extra layer of protection? I guess my question was if decrypting this info at run time (in a separate shell process as per the code included in the question) could expose it to attacker? Would it be as easy to read it (e.g by malicious software) as environment variables would be in the main shell process where django runs?